# GCP - outgoing connection

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have create a VM in GCP, opened for it port 80, the instance was centos 7
now I have tried to yum install wget - and failed with the error

> Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
>   Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
>   Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=7&arch=x86_64&repo=os&infra=stock error was

the instance has also public ip

in the firewall rules, I have also added egress rule for 0.0.0.0 on all types

but still cannot yum install wget

what am I missing?

Comment: Try `ping mirrorlist.centos.org`. If this does not work you have a networking problem or misconfigured firewall. If it does work try resetting yum `yum clean all` then `yum update`.

Comment: i can ping but i am failing with any other network commands, yum update also fails

Comment: FYI, you should not need to enable outbound firewall rules to accomplish this. For example, if you create a new instance in a new project with an external IP and you can SSH into it then you should also be able to do yum updates.